# Downloading multiple files from a url using selenium and renaming them

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

The code below is attempting to download data from a link that is modified by inserting the "tickers" list into a URL

I tried putting this within the for loop of URL but it produces an error because it tries to go through the entire tickers list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
import time
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

start = '10/26/2020'
end = '1/22/2023'
tickers = ["ap","dmc","creit","chib","fli","fb","dmc","fph","gma7","ltg",
           "mbt",",mreit","nikl","pse","rcr","rlc","rrhi","scc","secb"]

urls = [(f'https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/PH/{ticker}/historical-prices') for ticker in tickers]
path = "/Users/sef/Documents/Py-MSC/chromedriver_mac_arm64/chromedriver"

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('detatch', True)
s = Service(path)
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
folder = "/Users/sef/Documents/PSE_Data Repository"
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : folder}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chromeOptions)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(4)
    beg_date = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="selectDateFrom"]')
    beg_date.clear()
    beg_date.send_keys(start)
    end_date = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="selectDateTo"]')
    end_date.clear()
    end_date.send_keys(end)
    driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="datPickerButton"]').click()
    driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="dl_spreadsheet"]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
for ticker in tickers: 
label = ticker.upper()
    old = r'/Users/sef/Documents/PSE_Data Repository/HistoricalPrices.csv'
    new = f'/Users/sef/Documents/PSE_Data Repository/{label}.csv'
    os.rename(old, new)
```

How can I modify this so that it will only use the first item within the tickers list and then move on to the next item for the next loop of the URL.

```
for ticker in tickers: 
label = ticker.upper()
    old = r'/Users/sef/Documents/PSE_Data Repository/HistoricalPrices.csv'
    new = f'/Users/sef/Documents/PSE_Data Repository/{label}.csv'
    os.rename(old, new)
```

Comment: What's the error? And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Selenium, but it seems that if you restructure your `for` loop to loop over the tickers instead of the urls you can achieve your results.

I think your problem is that each loop that fetches data creates a file called 'HistoricalPrices.csv' and it gets overwritten each iteration. You need to perform the rename after each file download before the next iteration of the loop. To do this, loop over the tickers instead of the urls.

```
for ticker in tickers: 
    # get data & download file
    url = f'https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/PH/{ticker}/historical-prices'
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(4)
    beg_date = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="selectDateFrom"]')
    beg_date.clear()
    beg_date.send_keys(start)
    end_date = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="selectDateTo"]')
    end_date.clear()
    end_date.send_keys(end)
    driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="datPickerButton"]').click()
    driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="dl_spreadsheet"]').click()
    time.sleep(5)    
    
    # rename file
    label = ticker.upper()
    old = r'/Users/sef/Documents/PSE_Data Repository/HistoricalPrices.csv'
    new = f'/Users/sef/Documents/PSE_Data Repository/{label}.csv'
    os.rename(old, new)
```

Hopefully this solves your problem.